# Fetch data for a select query in yii migrations

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-migrations

I am creating a parent child table using yii migration where there is a foreign key on the child table. I tried using execute but that did not help me fetching the data needed. Is there a way I can query the parent table and insert the parent id on the child table as a foreign key? Something like fetch()/fetchAll() that is used inside phinx migrations.

```
    $this->batchInsert('{{%parent_table}}',
                ['name'],
                [
                    ['P1'],
                    ['P2'],
                    ['P3'],
                    ['P4']
                ]
            );
    $a = $this->execute("select * from parent_table where name = 'P1'");
    // get the data from the table that will get me the id from the above query.

    $this->batchInsert('{{%child_table}}',
                [['name'],['parent_id']],
                [
                    ['C1','<parent id>'],
                    ['C2','<parent id>'],
                    .
                    .
                    .
                ]
            );
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to create records in parent table using ActiveRecord models? You can create parent records in for/foreach cycle then use something like `$model->id` to get parent id for batch inserting child records.

Comment: @MichalHynčica: I want to create a migration script so that in future if we are to migrate the whole database these values are inserted directly in one single migration rather than creating a script using foreach. As the records are static it would be just a one time script anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
$sql = <<<SQL
select * from parent_table where name = 'P1'
SQL;

$res = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

The `$this->execute()` is used to execute sql statements like update or delete instead

**Edit**

Better use `$this->db` instead of `Yii::$app->db` to make sure you are running on the same db, as mentioned in the comments

Comment: It might be better to use `$this->db` component instead of `Yii::$app->db` to make sure you are running your query on same DB.